# Stripping template-ness and re-applying it: enumerate all cases for a simple getter function?

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

I make heavy use of templated C++ functions and objects in my coding, but I am encountering more situations where I want to take those templated objects, compiled with a C++ compiler, over to the CUDA layer of the program, and for that the solutions tend to carry a common thread of "remove templatedness" to transmit the object into a CUDA unit, include an integer code (good old `std::type_index(typeid(T)).hash_code`) that indicates the true nature, and then (re-)reinterpret the object as it truly is.

This can create a great lot of tedious code.

My question concerns whether it is possible, for an object such as `Coordinates<T>`, to use a generic reinterpretation to access members of the class (or getter functions to them) which do not depend on the template parameter.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <sys/types.h>

template <typename T> class Coordinates {
public:
  Coordinates(const int n_particles_in) :
    n_particles{n_particles_in}
  {}

  int getParticleCount() {
    return n_particles;
  }
private:
  int n_particles;
  T* x_positions;
  T* y_positions;
  T* z_positions;
};

void dealWithGenericCoordinates(Coordinates<void> *system, const size_t tidx) {
  Coordinates<float> *ptr = reinterpret_cast<Coordinates<float>*>(system);
  printf("There are %d particles\n", ptr->getParticleCount());
}

static const size_t double_type_index = std::type_index(typeid(double)).hash_code();
static const size_t float_type_index = std::type_index(typeid(float)).hash_code();

int main() {
  Coordinates<double> molecule(5);
  Coordinates<void> *mol_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Coordinates<void>*>(&molecule);

  dealWithGenericCoordinates(mol_ptr, double_type_index);
  return 0;
}
```

The above is about the minimum code I could get to compile and run.  When I do, I see the expected 'There are 5 particles.' message.  However, is this a general thing, is it *safe* to do this in any case so long as I do not need to access the template-dependent members of the object, or something that depends on the size of the template?  If I am correct, I would imagine that the object below would not let me access the number of particles from a pointer to some generic `FragileCoordinates<int>` if the original type was `<double>` or anything that had a size other than 4, and that even using the `getParticleCount()` method would fail.

```
template <typename T>
FragileCoordinates {
public:
  int getParticleCount();
private:
  T scale;
  int n_particles;
};
```

I suppose that the best practice would be to enumerate and recover the pointer to the object of the correct type, as future development may insert a member that depends on the template size, which then breaks any code that tries to read from a generic cast.  But, in the limited case where that does not happen, is it in fact safe to do as my full program above?